# How to count other posts of same name and date_posted as current post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I've this app in ruby on rails wherein I want to count all those posts having same title and date posted as the current post before saving the current po.

In my create method of post controller I'm doing something like-

```
@post = Post.new(post_params)
# @post.datepublished = it will be today's date
totalnoofposts = Post.count(:all, :conditions => "title = " @post.title " AND datepublished = " @post.datepublished)

# then I'll save the new post
```

I'm getting a long syntax error, Can anyone please help me how to count such posts this way?

Comment: That is an ancient syntax of Rails, what version are you using?

Comment: 5.1.7 I didn't know it was oldish syntax of rails

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Post.where(title: @post.title, datePublished: @post.datePublished).count
```

Also to note some things. It is a convention in RoR that the fields to be snake case i.e. date_published, instead of datePublished. As well as including the error message as well into the question.